# Error when creating a new user account

Tags: meteor, meteor-react

I'm trying to insert a new collection into the database when a user creates their account for the first time, however, I'm getting an error.

`Exception while invoking method 'createUser' TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined`

I've used similar code in the past and not had this problem.

Path: `imports/startup/server/newUser.js`

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Roles } from 'meteor/alanning:roles';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';
import { Documents } from '../../api/documents/documents.js';

Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
      if (options.profile) {
        user.profile = options.profile;
      }

      Documents.insert({
        title: "Test Title",
        body: "Test Body"
      })

      return user;
    });
```

Path: `imports/api/documents/documents.js`

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { SimpleSchema } from 'meteor/aldeed:simple-schema';
import { Factory } from 'meteor/dburles:factory';

const Documents = new Mongo.Collection('Documents');
export default Documents;

Documents.allow({
  insert: () => false,
  update: () => false,
  remove: () => false,
});

Documents.deny({
  insert: () => true,
  update: () => true,
  remove: () => true,
});

Documents.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    label: 'The title of the document.',
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    label: 'The body of the document.',
  },
});

Documents.attachSchema(Documents.schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB, you must first declare your documents collection as it follows:

```
var Documents = new Mongo.Collection('documents');
```

Then you should be able to use the usual MongoDB operations.

Comment: I'm using simple scheam from aldeed. I thought the new collection was defined within the api directory under documents

Comment: Are you invoking those instructions from the react client, or from meteor server?

Comment: I think you must define it first using  ``new SimpleSchema``

Comment: From the server

Comment: Are you defining the collection?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this was very simple. I posted this on the meteor forums and @jamgold provided the solution. Find answer [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/error-when-creating-a-new-user-account/35246/6).

I used:

`import { Documents } from '../../api/documents/documents.js';`

Importing with brackets was incorrect becuase I was using the `export default Documents`. It should have been:

`import Documents from '../../api/documents/documents.js';`